# How to get microsoft graph token without popup user login page?

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to write a backend app to read & write one company emailbox.
I have registered Active Directory Application and granted Delegated permissions (read and write to user mailbox).
Question is how to get the token needed for authenticate the graph api calls(for example ListMessages). 
From the document I coundn't find any working example for backend app aquiring token and make api calls.

There are two endpoint versions:
**Azure AD and Azure AD v2.0 endpoints;**
And two authentication method:
**1. Get access on behalf of a user**
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user
**2. Get access without a user**
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

What shoud I use ? Really confused.
Thanks all.

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question. What is your scenario like? Is the user logged in while you call the APIs? The initial token you need to get with the login page, then you can get a refresh token to get new tokens as needed. Though that does depend on your app type.

Comment: @juunas Thanks for your reply. I want to skip login page for initial token fetch, say, it all happen backend without user presence. Can I do this by grant_type=password with username and password of the resource owner ?

Comment: You can't do _both_ Delegated permissions _and_ App-Only (aka Client Credentials) authentication. Delegated scopes require a user to authenticate and consent to your app accessing their data. Application scopes only require an Admin to authorize your app once, afterward it can simply obtain a token.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I assume you want to get an access token without user login page.

Based on my test, we can get an access token that run as a background services or daemons.

It requires administrator to grant the access permission once, then user will not see login popup window anymore.

For more detail, we can refer to [this official document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you mean I need to grant application permission in azure portal ?

Comment: You can rely on an administrator to grant the permissions your app needs at the Azure portal. And when we login the site, it will request the administrator to grant permission.

Comment: Can I do this totally 'human free' ? its a backend app, so it will not involve user actions.

Comment: Yes, you can do it as a background services

Comment: I want to do this only with delegated permissions. Couldn't find a valid grant flow in this senario

Comment: From the official document, there are two ways to grant. If you use the delegated permissions, i think the `login popup` is needed

Comment: Thanks Kikang, Thats all I need to know.

Comment: OK, it can help you, I am very happy. Could you please you mark it as answer to help more people

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for Resource Owner Password Credentials grant flow.
However its usage is not recommended.

It does not work in these scenarios:

- User has MFA
- User password has expired
- User is federated (MS account/Google/on-prem AD)

The only scenario that I can think of where this flow is okay is integration tests of APIs where you need to test scenarios where you call your API on behalf of a user.

Here is a better way to do what you want:

- Require an application permission to access user emails and have the admin grant it. Now you can use client credentials grant flow to get a token anytime you need one.
- Use delegated permissions, have the user sign in once with Authorization Code grant flow. Then exchange the code for an access token and a refresh token. Store at least the refresh token somewhere secure. Use refresh token whenever you need a new token.

The first approach is more reliable but requires broader permissions.
The second has tighter security (only users who have authorized access can have their email read), but has slightly less reliability.
Refresh tokens can be invalidated, in which case you'll need the user to login again.

Comment: Thanks thats what I'm looking for, but I dont know if microsoft graph support this grant flow or not. I keep getting invalid username and password error when using grant type = password.